# Transform an array into a range

Tags: excel, vba, range, object-model

normally, I do not bother with the range object in VBA Excel since I very often run into problems even after studying background information (=> "Object not found etc.").
But I encountered a function
worksheetfunction.rank
which does not like arrays, but needs a range.

Despite all my efforts, I could not get my array into a range.
Last effort has been a workaround:
writing data on a (hidden) worksheet from the array, then take the range from there.
I packaged this in a user-defined function but it does not work.
So, I would kindly ask the community here to take a look.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
Function Transform_Array_into_Range(Feld() As Variant) As Range
'Uses Worksheet "For_Range_Transform" to transform an Array into a range
'Only one column !;   needs Option Base 1

Dim rng As Range
Dim lowercounter As Integer
Dim highercounter As Integer
Dim i As Integer

lowercounter = LBound(Feld())
highercounter = UBound(Feld())

Set rng = Worksheets("For_Range_Transform").Range("A1:A1")
Debug.Print (rng(1))

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("For_Range_Transform").Cells.ClearContents

If lowercounter > 1 Then
 Set rng = Range("A1:A1").Resize(highercounter, 1)
 ' Worksheets("For_Range_Transform").rng.Resize = rng(UBound(Feld()), 1)
 ' Set rng = Range("A1:A1").Resize(highercounter, 1).Select
  
End If


For i = 1 To highercounter
    rng(i).Value = Feld(i)
Next i


End Function
```

```
Sub Test_of_UDF_Transform_Array_into_Range()
'gives error
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrF(1 To 5) As Variant
Dim rngR As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

For i = 1 To 5
    arrF(i) = i
Next i

Set rngR = Worksheets("For_Range_Transform").Range("A1:A1")

Set rngR = Transform_Array_into_Range(arrF())

Debug.Print (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("For_Range_Transform").rngR(2).Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: A UDF can't write to a sheet - see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.

Comment: OK, thanks, this certainly explains the error.

Comment: Instead of using `worksheetfunction.rank` you could sort your array and loop over the sorted array to find the rank.

Comment: I found it strange that I could not use a relatively typical Excel function. Is there any other way to convert an array into a range?

Comment: A Range object can't exist independently of a worksheet.

Comment: So, the workaround is basically the right idea or any other thoughts? (Thanks!)

Comment: If you want to do this in code called from a UDF, and your list of values is not already in a range, then likely the best approach would be to roll your own version of `Rank`